# Click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a jquery which has a click event, when any anchor tag is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("a").click(function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();               
        $('#myModal').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#myModal').reveal();
    });    
});
```

I also have another anchor with the id 'close'. I want he click event to run for when any of the anchor is clicked except for one which has 'close' id. The other anchor doesn't have id.

How can i achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems as if you have described the `if()` syntax you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("a:not('#close')").click(function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();               
        $('#myModal').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#myModal').reveal();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the 'not' metaselector.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$(function () {
  $("a:not(#close)").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();               
    $('#myModal')
      .load($(this).attr('href'))
      .reveal();
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("a[id!='close']").click(function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();               
        $('#myModal').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#myModal').reveal();
    });    
});
```